# Why do we use resistor along with the transistor?

Tags: led, transistors, resistors

from the knowledge i have, i know that a transistor is a special kind of resistor that can change it's resistance depending on the input at it's base.

**questions**  sorry for the big picture

=> Why do we need a resistor(R4) when we already have a transistor(Q4)? Won't it work as a resistor?

[image]

Comment: The fact that you will delete the question shows that you are willingly trying to abuse the stackexchange website.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that, then i won't be deleting it :) @pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on HOW you are using Q4.  The typical application as shown in your diagram is to use Q4 as a simple ON / OFF switch. We inject the base with enough current to drive Q4 into "saturation" so that it is conducting as much as possible. In that case, R4 is required to limit the amount of current flowing through LED4.

An LED will self-destruct if you allow it to draw unlimited amounts of current and it will toast itself.

OTOH, if we were somehow monitoring the amount of current through LED4, we could adjust the amount that Q4 is conducting to limit the current through LED4. But that would require a different kind of circuit than the one you show.

Comment: clearly understood what you mean to say, thank you sir @Richard Crowley

Answer (score 1):

You've only shown part of the circuit but the mode of operation in this circuit is to use the transistor as an on-off switch.

- With no base current it is fully off.
- With adequate base current it is fully or "hard" on.

This mode of operation is very simple and very reliable.

> Why do we need a resistor(R4) when we already have a transistor(Q4)? Won't it work as a resistor?

You are correct in that if you control the current into the base-emitter junction of a transistor you can control the current that passes between the collector-emitter terminals. The ratio of current gain is given by the \$h_{FE}\$ parameter and for the transistor in your circuit might be about 100 to 200. (I didn't look it up.)

We might expect then that if we want 10 mA through the LED then 0.1 mA into the base should do the trick. The problem is that the \$h_{FE}\$ will vary from part to part, may vary with voltage and temperature, etc., and to make this work reliably we need to complicate the circuit and provide feedback so that it is self-regulating. For applications like LEDs, relays and digital switching in general it's much simpler and more reliable to use hard switching. It has become the basis of digital computing.

Transistors in variable resistance mode are used in amplifiers (including op-amps) and linear voltage regulators. If you examine these circuits you will learn about feedback methods used to ensure the desired output.